# Asset classes: Is a Guaranteed Investment Certificate (GIC) considered a bond?

Tags: canada, investing, bonds, asset-class

When we think of asset classes, there are 2 types: stocks and bonds. Where does an investment like a GIC fit in? It is not a bond, nor is it a stock.

Comment: There are more than 2 types of asset classes.  You're only mentioning perhaps the *top* 2 that come to mind.  Cash, commodities, real estate, etc. are examples of some others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a third type of asset that a GIC falls into: **Cash**.

So while it does share some characteristics of a bond, such as (often) having a fixed interest rate, and having the ability to *ladder* their maturities, they would generally be considered part of your Cash component of your portfolio.

Comment: in my opinion, cash implies liquidity, and GICs are not necessarily liquid.  Certainly cashable GICs are essentially cash-equivalent, but not when there's an early withdrawal penalty.

Comment: IMHO, I would tend to look at either cashable or short-term GICs (less than 1 year to maturity) as cash-equivalent, and consider the rest as fixed-income.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of "stocks" I would refer to that asset class as "equity."  Instead of bonds, I would refer to that asset class as "fixed income."  Given that more general terminology, GICs would fit into fixed income.